# go LoadDLL with dependencies not in System or System32

Tags: go

I am trying to load a library from GO on windows as:

```
citect, err := syscall.LoadDLL("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AVEVA Plant SCADA\\Bin\\Bin (x64)CtApi.dll")
```

The problem is that this library has dependencies also in that directory.  The result is an error "The specified module could not be found."  I am pretty sure it's failing because of unmet dependencies in other DLLs.

Is there some way from syscall to force the DLL search path?

**UPDATE**

I think the issue I was having was because I was specifying LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS but the library I am trying to load needs the standard search path as well.  I added LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS and now it gives me a Handle that makes sense.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    dllPath := "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AVEVA Plant SCADA\\Bin\\Bin (x64)"

    kernel, _ := windows.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    defer kernel.Release()

    sdd, err := kernel.FindProc("SetDefaultDllDirectories")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r1, _, err := sdd.Call(windows.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)
    if r1 == 0 {
        panic(err)
    }

    addd, err := kernel.FindProc("AddDllDirectory")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    chars := StringToWideCharPtr(dllPath)

    r1, _, err = addd.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(chars)))
    fmt.Printf("result of add dll directory: %d\n", r1)
    if r1 == 0 {
        panic(err)
    }

    h, err := windows.LoadLibraryEx("CtApi.dll", 0, 0)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("library: %v\n", h)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `LoadLibraryEx` in the `golang.org/x/sys/windows` package, which supports the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_*` flags (see [Search order using LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-using-load_library_search-flags)).

```golang
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    name := "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AVEVA Plant SCADA\\Bin\\Bin (x64)CtApi.dll"
    h, err := windows.LoadLibraryEx(name, 0, windows.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dll := &windows.DLL{
        Name:   name,
        Handle: h,
    }

    // use the dll
}
```

Please note that the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_*` flags are not available on all windows versions. See [code comments here](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/6c5289959c9811faffd66524f62cdcda16aa2d5c/windows/dll_windows.go#L357-L364).

Comment: This seems like it's close but not quite.  On the LoadLibraryEx I still get 'module not found' for some reason.  I modified my original question to show what I am trying now.

Comment: `If SetDefaultDllDirectories is first called with LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS, directories specified with AddDllDirectory are added to the process DLL search path. Otherwise, directories specified with the AddDllDirectory function are used only for LoadLibraryEx function calls that specify LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory

Comment: Yes, I did notice that mistake and changed it.  I hink don't need the SetDefaultDllDirectories at all, it seems that I should be able to just Add and include LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS.  So I'm still not sure why 'module not found'

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect the latest code? I don't see `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS` is specified.

Comment: Dependency Walker is telling me what may be the problem.  It finds all the dependencies at the top level but some of them - for example VCRUNTIME140_1.DLL it says needs a bunch of deps it can't find like API-MS-WIN-CRT-RU NTIME-L1-1-0.DLL ... they all seem to start API-MS-WIN

Comment: I think I have it.  I think I need both windows.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS and windows.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS
```